# Removing empty sublists from nested list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How do I get from this:

```
a = [[[1, 1], [], [2,2]], [[2,2], [], [1, 1]]]
```

to this:

```
a = [[[1,1], [2,2]], [[2,2], [1,1]]]
```

quickly? I am trying to use a list comprehension but can't figure it out.

Comment: try this ; `[[l for l in lst if l!=[]] for lst in a ]`

Comment: How many nested levels? Can you have different nested levels per list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
a = [[sublst for sublst in lst if sublst] for lst in a]
```

Otherwise you can use the `filter` function:

```
[list(filter(None, lst)) for lst in a]
```

Comment: it is faster to use ```if sublst``` than ```if sublst != []```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```py
a=[[i for i in lst if i] for lst in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

this solution is working for me.

```
a = [[[1, 1], [], [2,2]], [[2,2], [], [1, 1]]]
list_new = []
for i in a :
    list_new.append([x for x in i if x != []])
```